# entry point of docker container dependent on local file system and not in the image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a docker container that is being created from a generic image. The entry point of this container is dependent on a file in the local file system and not in the generic image. My docker-compose file looks something like this:

```
service_name:
    image: base_generic_image
    container_name: container_name 
    entrypoint: 
    - "/user/dlc/bin"
    - "-p"
    - "localFolder/fileName.ext"
    - more parameters
```

The challenge that I am facing is removing this dependency and adding it to the base_generic_image at run time so that I can deploy it independently. Should I add this file to the base generic image and then proceed(this file is not required by others) or should this be done when creating the container, if so then what is the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate image for each part of your application.  These can be based on the base image if you'd like; the Dockerfile might look like

```
FROM base_generic_image
COPY dlc /usr/bin
CMD ["dlc"]
```

Your Docker Compose setup might have a subdirectory for each component and could look like

```
servicename:
  image: my/servicename
  build:
    context: ./servicename
  command: ["dlc", "-p", ...]
```

In general Docker volumes and bind-mounts are good things to use for persistent data (when absolutely required; stateless containers with external databases are often easier to manage), getting log files out of containers, and pushing complex configuration into containers.  The actual program that's being run generally should be built into the base image.  The goal is that you can take the image and `docker run` it on a clean system without any of your development environment on it.